# How do I downgrade php from 5.4 to 5.3 in CentOS?

Tags: centos, php, yum, downgrade

I have a webserver running CentOS 6. Yesterday, I installed php-gd with `yum install php-gd` because I couldn't see graphics on my website. However, when I see my php version, it changed from 5.3 to 5.4x.

Because my application uses `register_globals` (which was removed from php 5.4), I cant even log in to my app.

I tried two ways to downgrade my php:

1. Using yum again to downgrade; this wouldn't downgrade to 5.3x, just 5.4x
2. Downloading the php rpm directly; I messed this up, and wound up with dependency hell.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply fix your code - According to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1973028
add the following to the top of your PHP script -

foreach ($_REQUEST as $key=>$val) {
    ${$key}=$val;
}

(And ask yourself why you are running insecure code).

Apparently you can even automate this further by adding an "auto_prepend_file" directive to a .htaccess file to make it work for the entire directory in 1 hit.